# Как получить ширину и высоту разрешения телефона для эмуляции в Chrome DevTools?

Tags: html, css, frontend, google-chrome-devtools

Всем доброго времени суток!

Хочу узнать как лендинг выглядит на Iphone 11, Iphone 12, Xiaomi Mi A1 и других устройствах. Нужных мне устройств нету в Toogle Device Toolbar (Ctrl + Shift + m) -> Edit -> Devices в Chrome DevTools. Как мне узнать какую ширину и высоту задавать в Toogle Device Toolbar -> Responsive, чтобы получить картинку как на нужных мне устройствах?

Благодарю за внимание..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наиболее точный эмулятор айфона https://appetize.io/ , но бесплатно всего минуту.
Остальные устройства тестируйте в браузере, попиксельно меняя высоту и ширину.